# Improper integral of a periodic real function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I wanted to prove that the improper integral of a periodic function diverges : let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a periodic continuous function of period $T$ and $f \neq 0$. I want to prove that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx \text { does not converge}$$

I do not really know how to prove it (maybe it is not even true). I tried to say that $$\int_0^T f(x) dx = l \neq 0 \implies \int_0^{2T} f(x) dx = 2l \implies \cdots \implies \int_0^{nT} f(x) dx = nl $$

So when $n$ goes to $\infty$ we have that $$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = ± \infty $$
But what happens if $\int_0^T f(x) dx = l=0$ ? And is my proof for the case $l\neq 0$ correct ?

Comment: does the $0$ function count as a periodic real function? For other functions where the integral is $0$ you get the the definite integral from $0$ to $x$ is also a periodic function, and for a periodic function to converge when $x$ goes to infinity it must be constant (and in this case equal to $0$ because the integral from $0$ to $0$ is $0$ ).

Comment: Before asking anymore questions, please consider going back and accepting the previous answers you have received. It's considered proper etiquette on this site to upvote and accept answers you find useful as a means of thanking those who helped you and highlighting useful answers for future viewers of your questions!

Answer (score 1):

For $l=0$ your proof is corrcet. Now note that for $0<x<T$ we have $\int_0^{x} f(t) dt =\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T+x} f(t)dt \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. Hence $\int_0^{x} f(t) dt=0$ for each $x \in (0,T)$ which implies that $f(x)=0$ for $0 <x<T$. By periodicity this gives $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought: some periodic functions it will not necessarily converge, but it does not diverge either, For example:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)\,dx=0$$ so:
$$\int_0^{2\pi n}\sin(x)\,dx=0\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
if we took $n\to\pm\infty$ this would go to zero (keeping it as an integer of course) but we could also represent it as:
$$-1\le\int_0^{(n+k)2\pi}\sin(x)\,dx\le 1\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},k\in(0,1)$$ as any number could be represented as $n$ full periods and then a fractional part of a final period. Whilst this integral does not converge on a given value (it is undefined) it is also not divergent

---

Whilst $\sin(x)=0$ at some points, there are many functions (unit impulses etc) that you could define periodically that would also have this nature.

In summary:
$$\text{if }\,f(x+T)=f(x),\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx\ne0\Rightarrow\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx \,\,\text{does not converge}$$